# Search and Replace URL - Regex?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to create a WordPress shortcode (the WordPress part of it isn't that relevant) that will search within some specified text for a link and replace it with one that I specify. For example:

```
[scode]Click on <a href="www.X.com">this link</a>[scode]
[scode]Click on <a href="www.Y.com">this link</a>[scode]
```

...will be changed to:

```
[scode]Click on <a href="www.Z.com">this link</a>[scode]
```

I'm trying to put together a function that will search for links and replace them with the one  that I specify. Here's what I have right now:

```
// Adds [hide] shortcode for hiding content from non-registered users.

function hide_text( $atts,$content) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in () ) {
        return $content;
    }
    else {
        $pattern = '(?<=href=("|\'))[^"\']+(?=("|\'))';
        $newurl = "http://replacementurl.com";
        $content = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$content);
        echo $content;
          }
    }
add_shortcode( 'hide', 'hide_text' );
```

This just crashes the site, though. I'm not a PHP expert (much less an expert on regex), but are there at least any glaring irregularities in my code?

**UPDATE:**

I ran debug on the site and found out from the log that there was an extra `}` in there. Now the site isn't crashing, but the content being echoed is blank... Code updated above

Comment: When it crashes do you get an error?

Comment: @DavidStarkey yeah, cannot connect to server. Usual error whenever there's some screwed up code.

Answer (score 1):

`http://replcaement url.com` Pretty sure this is spelled incorrectly.

and there isn't an `;` at the end of the line.

Looks like you've done the regex correctly for the most part you also need to escape some reserved characters look at @Akam's answer.

I suggest using [preg quotes.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

```
(?<=href=("|'))[^"']+(?=("|'))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/tCRqEsn6Ip2RML02)

Comment: This would work better as a comment as it would not be the reason the site is crashing.

Comment: That looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error in your pattern, change it to:

```
    $pattern = "(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))";
```

Errors:

```
    $pattern = "(?<=href=("|'))[^"']+(?=("|'))";
                          ^--            ^--not escaped
```

Comment: This doesn't "crash" the site, but no content loads whatsoever.